# DVC | ERROR: unexpected error - _register_s3_control_events() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python-3.x, bash, amazon-s3, dvc

Only as of recently, have I had this error with DVC.

Tracback:

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ dvc push
ERROR: unexpected error - _register_s3_control_events() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given                                                                                                                                                          

Having any troubles? Hit us up at https://dvc.org/support, we are always happy to help!

(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ dvc doctor
DVC version: 2.28.0 (pip)
---------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.9.13 on Linux-5.15.0-52-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Subprojects:
        dvc_data = 0.13.0
        dvc_objects = 0.5.0
        dvc_render = 0.0.11
        dvc_task = 0.1.2
        dvclive = 0.12.1
        scmrepo = 0.1.1
Supports:
        http (aiohttp = 3.8.3, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        https (aiohttp = 3.8.3, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        s3 (s3fs = 2022.10.0, boto3 = 1.24.59)
Cache types: hardlink, symlink
Cache directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Caches: local
Remotes: s3
Workspace directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Repo: dvc, git
```

`.dvc/config/`:

```
[core]
    remote = storage
    autostage = true
['remote "storage"']
    url = s3://bucket/project/dvcstore/
```

Let me know if I should add anything else to the post.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Can be a discrepancy in some libraries versions - boto, s3fs, etc. Could you please try to install the latest DVC version in a clean env? Also, could you please run `dvc push -v` to get the full stack trace? Thanks!

Comment: Ticket is here https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/8513#issuecomment-1298773276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

[`pip check`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_check/) checks whether dependencies for installed packages are compatible.

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ pip check
# ...
aiobotocore 2.4.0 has requirement botocore<1.27.60,>=1.27.59, but you have botocore 1.29.0.
```

I had installed packages with conflicting dependencies. i.e. Packages that required different, but default, versions of `botocore`.

Hence why recreating `venv` didn't work.

In my case, I had to:

```
conda install botocore==1.27.59
dvc push
```

And `dvc push` was working again :)